# Create Webhooks in ASP.NET Core

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, webhooks

Is there any way to create Webhooks in ASP.NET Core?

I looked into https://github.com/aspnet/WebHooks but I can't find support for ASP.NET Core

Answer (score 7, accepted):

WebHooks will be rolled out with the ASP.NET Core 2.1 release, as announced here:
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2018/02/02/asp-net-core-2-1-roadmap/#webhooks.

Update: WebHooks was pulled out of 2.1 and has moved to the 2.2 release.

Comment: This is correct, here's a link with announcement: https://github.com/aspnet/Announcements/issues/299 (they only exists in preview form)

Answer (score 3):

Scott is right. ASP.NET Core 2.1 supports webhooks and since the preview is already out, you can create webhooks with ASP.NET Core. Here is a [Github repository](https://github.com/talkingdotnet/ASPNETCore_WebhooksSample/) having sample for DropBox and Github Webhooks with ASP.NET Core. You can also visit [this](http://www.talkingdotnet.com/webhooks-with-asp-net-core-dropbox-and-github/) post to know more in detail about the implementation.